# AS3 combo box referencing xml

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm pretty new to actionscript, I have this scenerio. I have a combo box "elementPicker", I have a project that loads images from an XML file, the XML file is set up like

```
<elements>
<head>
   <imgpath>/img/x.png</imgpath>
</head>
<head>...</head>
<head>...</head>

<eyes>...</eyes>
<eyes>...</eyes>
<eyes>...</eyes>
</elements>
```

And so on, so in my combo box I'll have options like "head", "eyes", and so on. What I want is based on the data in the combo box to change which xml element gets loaded into my array that holds the image paths

I tried something like

```
var comboSelection:String = elementPicker.selectedItem.label;
```

then, when I'm looping to put the paths in the array:

```
elementPathList.push(theXMLData.comboSelection.imgpath[ b ]);
```

But this isn't working, the output shows: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I completely understand the issue but the type error is telling you that comboSelection (literally, not the value but that word) doesn't exist as a property of your theXMLData object, which based on what you posted is true.

comboSelection isn't being "seen" as the local variable you created or it's value but rather as a property of theXMLData object which it isn't hence the type error.

It seems what you want to do is find the item in the list with the corresponding property, you can use E4X to achieve this, google it you'll find details on using e4x it would be something like theXMLData.(@nodeName=comboSelection).head.imgpath.

However I think a better way to go would be to populate the combo box with value objects that both have the label property and have the actual source path associated with the object directly.  In that way you can just use the elementPicker.selectedItem.imgPath instead of attempting to look it up in the XML after the fact.  This solution will make the code less confusing and faster.  If you can't do this yourself you could post more code regarding your combo box and how you're loading in your XML I can help you modify that to achieve what I'm explaining.

If the code is quite large you can post it to pastebin and just drop a link in your original post.

Alright since you appeased me I took a crack at it here's my two results:

http://www.shaunhusain.com/FlashAvaEditor/

http://www.shaunhusain.com/FlexAvaEditor/

right click the flex one for source, I packaged the files for the FLA one here

http://www.shaunhusain.com/FlashAvaEditor/FlashAvaEditor.zip

Let me know what you think of this approach, or if I missed the mark.

Comment: Thanks! Here's the actionscript file that loads and places the elements from XML http://pastebin.com/rE8HtLqE

I hope you get what I'm trying to do :) I had to take ideas from flash based galleries and modify them to my needs, basically the end result will layer elements atop eachother to create an avvie.

Comment: Yah I follow the general concept, the code you posted will help for sure if you don't mind please also post some sample XML, it can be just two nodes or something just so I have a full view of the structure and something to work with to debug locally, otherwise it will be more back and forth no doubt (one full node would be okay but there's some differences in how single results vs sets are treated in E4X so if more than one is the norm a couple is better to test with).  This way I'll take you're original stuff drop it in a sample project and test then have a full project to pass back.

Comment: Oh sure, here's the basic xml structure http://pastebin.com/01920XGN

there'll be more to it than that my idea is to have it set up so if i create a new avvie element i can just pop it in the xml and viola. 

some of the vars that aren't defined in that file are defined in another as file, which looks like http://pastebin.com/Nbh8gsEN .. so all those elements will load into a new movie clip ultimately. 

btw here's the thumbnail loading bit : http://pastebin.com/j1ZNafmQ just so u have the full idea.

thanks for the help

Comment: Sorry one more actually important question I need to ask, are you using Flex/FlashBuilder or are you using the "regular" Flash IDE.  I'm more familiar and comfortable with Flex but am pretty well accustomed to any AS3 so either way will do but I just want to know what version of the combo list you'll be actually using.  I'm going to assume Flex at the moment (really just for the combo component and speed of development) although I don't see any indication but I can "back-port" the code to work without the Flex components if needed.  The concept should map 1:1 anyhow.

Comment: I'm using Adobe Flash Professional CS5.5 so I guess that would be the "regular" IDE :) & no need to apologize I should have been more clear from the start you're a big help!

Comment: Alright since I had gone down the flex path I just threw it up on my server, popped open Flash IDE gotta blow the dust off and I'll see what I can put together: http://www.shaunhusain.com/FlexAvaEditor/

Comment: Also what is the type of elementPicker is that a custom component you made or are you using some open source package that has that class?  This is a big I dunno with regard to doing this in Flash IDE that made me instantly think it was Flex.

Comment: the elementPicker is the instance name of the combo box in adobe flash cs5.5, which holds the different types of elements in other words "head", "hair", "eyes", etc, which based on what ones picked i want to tell the as to load those specific elements into the movie clips.

Comment: letting my Flash IDE ignorance shine here didn't realize they had a combo as part of the default UI components in there, using that I presume.

Comment: btw the last reference that might be a bit ambiguous is the scrollpane element (instance name elementHolder) where thumbs are loaded, once a thumb is clicked it loads the bigger image from xml.

so just in summary youll have all these layering movie clips holding elements like head, hair, eyes etc. a combo box which loads different elements in the scrollpane all from the xml file. pick head,  get head thumbnails, pick eyes get eye thumbnails, etc